# Deploy single-file app in Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I need to deploy a `single-file` app made in Shiny into a `shiny server`. The problem is that this app is called in a function, so there's no typical `server-ui` file structure. The structure is something like this:

```
/
├── ShinyMethods.R
    └── shinyApp()
```

And the code:

```
shinyApp <- function() {
  app <- list(ui = NULL, server = NULL)
  app$ui <- fluidPage(...)
  app$server <- function(input, output, session) {...}
}
```

I don't know if `shinyServer` allows to deploy a single file app. Any idea?

Comment: have you tried it with `app.R` (the usual single file approach) already?

Comment: Yes, I already tried it but it doesn't work. It crashes. Maybe for the dependences. `.log` file doesn't show any error.